# Perl Regex Help

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking to match strings out of a file that are prefixed

```
/**
```

and have a postfix

```
*/
```

With any number of characters/whitespace/newlines in between.

eg:

```
/** anything
    anything
*/
```

I have `m/(\/\*\*).*?(\*\/)/` so far, however this does not handle newlines.  I know the fix has to be simple, but i have very limited regular expressions experience.
Bonus question: Does anyone have a good website for learning regular expressions?

Comment: O'Reilly has a great book for learning regular expressions. You get one guess as to what the title is. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `s` [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) after it:

```
m/(\/\*\*).*?(\*\/)/s
```

But if it's source code you're operating on, be careful:

```
print 'a string /**';
int a = b + c;
print '*/';

// /**
a = a - c;
// */
```

There really is but one online resource if it comes to learning regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Note that I'm not saying there don't exist other good online resources, but the one I posted should be sufficient for anyone new to regex to get a good understanding of how to use regex-es.

Answer (score 0):

Without using /s with make '.' behave differently, the following should work too:

```
m/(\/\*\*)(\r?\n|.)*(\*\/)/
```

For a place to learn perl?

http://perldoc.perl.org/
http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html
This is my ultimate reference, always.

But if you don't like to read something in a manual style which is a bit bore. 
Try Jeffrey Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions from O'Reilly, which is more interesting.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570

Comment: Instead of `(\r?\n|.)`, you could do: `[\s\S]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific regex (with newlines) can be matched with `\/\*\*[\d\D]*?\*\/` A side effect of `\D` is that it matches newlines and can be used in this manner.

In Perl, you can also use [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2010010201/) for finding a whole variety of source code comments.

There have already been mentioned some of the best links (Friedl's book and  http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

My web sites for regex are these:

1. Perl [perlre tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). The best intro to Perl's regex.
2. Perl [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) Perl's regex documentation
3. Perl [perlre quick reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) The quick start guide
4. [Regular Expressions, A Favorite Parsetime](http://japhy.perlmonk.org/articles/misc/LM-regex.html)
5. [Pattern Matching, Regular Expressions and Parsing Tutorials](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Tutorials#Pattern-Matching-Regular-Expressions-and-Parsing) at Perlmonks
6. [Explain Regex](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)
7. [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) Online Regular Expression Tester
8. [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/)
9. [Regex Powertoy](http://regex.powertoy.org/) online tester
10. [BRE and ERE](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/re.html) reference
11. Larry Wall's [Apocalypse 5: Pattern Matching](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/doc/design/apo/A05.html)